# Regex that removes all non-alphanumeric, single periods, and single slashes

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to whitelist characters for filenames and prevent path manipulation.  We take a filename returned from the frontend (i know.) and parse it to determine if it's in a specified folder.  As such we need to make sure the user isn't passing in a file that could escape out of the specified folder.  This means our case for a valid filename is:

- Alphanumeric
- Can include single slashes of either direction
- Can include single dots but not pairs.

So "APP-TEST-file.20161115.1" is valid but "/../../test//\" needs to have some characters removed prior to checking the filesystem.

Here's the regex I've got now, unfortunately it's removing too much.

```
public static String validateFilePath(String fileName) {
    return fileName.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9]+[(\\.\\/)\\+2]", "");
}
```

Such that "APP-TEST-file.20161115.1" is becoming  "APP-TEST-file0161115.1"

Any help would be appriciated.

Comment: Removing the `+2` changes `"/../../test//\"` to `"test"` but leaves `"APP-TEST-file.20161115.1"` intact. Is this the desired output?

Comment: Please post some representative input and expected output.

Comment: Is there a reason this has to be done with one regex?  A small handful of them would be a lot easier to write and read.

Comment: FYI: `APP-TEST-file.20161115.1` is not valid according to your rules, since it contains a dash (`-`).

Comment: @zero01alpha that works great, but it doesn't cover some of my (non-posted edge cases) which is my fault. If i could give you fake internet points know that I would.  I've decided to go for a more modular approach ala Wasi Ahmad's answer.

Comment: @Andreas I just realized this and it's because I used the wrong test case.  That's for a different bit of code.  I'll update my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want something like this? (I am not clear about what you want!)

```
String filename = "APP-TEST-file.20161115.1";
// replace two consecutive dots with a single dot
filename = filename.replaceAll("\\.+", ".");
// replace two consecutive forward slash with a single forward slash
filename = filename.replaceAll("/+", "/");
// replace two consecutive baskslash with a backslash
filename = filename.replaceAll("\\\\+", "\\\\");
// allow alphanumeric characters, dots and both type of slashes
filename = filename.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9./\\\\]+", "");
System.out.println(filename);
```

It prints:

```
APPTESTfile.20161115.1
```

If `filename="/../../test//\\"`, then it prints - `/././test/\`.

Comment: I am a fool and should have been doing this all along. This is what I get for trying to shoehorn a big regex in.  Thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't ``//\\`` be collapsed to ``/`` or ``\``, according to the *"Can include single slashes of either direction"* rule? Your code collapsed to ``/\``.

Comment: @Andreas what i have understood, OP wants to collapse // to / and \\ to \. that's why i wrote that. anyway, i wasn't sure as you can see i have written in my post - `I am not clear about what you want!`.